# Prefetching data with Nuxt to improve loading time

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

As far as I understand people are using server side rendering (ssr) to improve user experience and SEO with fast and content ready pages.

Recently I've started project with vue+nuxt in ssr mode.
What I've noticed is that when I try to prefetch data in nuxtServerInit action I have to wait for the async call to finish before page could be served to me.
As far as I know it will only hurt SEO and user experience.

```
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }) {
    const response = await this.$axios.$get('games')
    commit('setGameList', response.data)
  }
}
```

Is there a way to actually prefetch data once and cache it for some period of time so that users would not be forced to wait?

Also what is the good usecase for nuxtServerInit? Cant understand the purpose of it..

Comment: You should implement your own cache store and retrieve

Comment: @Aldarund, do you know what is the valid usecase for nuxtServerInit?

Comment: It's for loading app wide data from server. The thing is that if you want cache for it you need to implement it yoursrlf in nuxtserverinit. ( Or use some cache module for axios )

Comment: @Aldarund, what is "app wide data"? is data that defines routes of the website is a good example? I think so but for the crawler bot it will mean that the loading time increases, because webpage would not be served until request is finishes and nuxt renders.. which is bad, right?

Comment: But if you need that data to render page you need that data, you need to get it from somewhere. App wide data - e.g data that is used on all or most of pages

Comment: @Aldarund, that the point - my goal is the best possible SEO. Some requests are needed indeed for most of the pages but are useless for SEO as I don't care if search engine will index that info. So for those cases I don't want nuxt to wait before it will get this info. Still having difficulties deciding what method should I use in that case..

Comment: You can then just put it into mounted hook in layout

Answer (score 0):

Use [The fetch Method](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/)

```
<template>
  <h1>Stars: {{ $store.state.stars }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async fetch ({ store, params }) {
    let { data } = await axios.get('http://my-api/stars')
    store.commit('setStars', data)
  }
}
</script>
```

Remember to use Vuex to work well!

---

**UPDATE: How to share the fetch function**

1 - Create a file with the function:

```
// defaultFetch.js
module.exports = async function defaultFetch({ store, params }){
  // Put some developer magic here to make the code works for you
  let { data } = await axios.get('http://my-api/stars');
  store.commit('setStars', data);
}
```

2 - Import and use in other components

```
// amazingComoponent1.vue
<template>
  <h1>Stars: {{ $store.state.stars }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
import defaultFetch from "../utils/defaultFetch";
export default {
  fetch: defaultFetch
}
</script>



// amazingComoponent2.vue
<template>
  <h1>Stars: {{ $store.state.stars }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
import fetch from "../utils/defaultFetch";
export default {
  fetch,
}
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE 2: How to use and configure axios intance**

Very easy, update the defaultFetch.js:

```
// defaultFetch.js

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});

module.exports = async function defaultFetch({ store, params }){
  // Put some developer magic here to make the code works for you
  let { data } = await instance.get('http://my-api/stars');
  store.commit('setStars', data);
}
```

Hope helps :)

Comment: Good point but I need to fetch something that most of the pages will be using so I want to avoid code duplication(fetch method) in each page.

Comment: I just update the answer to show how to share the fetch function 

Comment: thx man, its almost something I can use except of the fact that defaultFetch need to have access to already configured by nuxt instance of axios. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: And how fetch will solve his problem? Page still will wait for it to load before render, same as nuxtserverinit

Comment: Use [Vuex+localstorage](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) to avoid fetch always data on client side.

Comment: to avoid fetching clientside I use process.client in fetch func and do not fire request if it's true. Problem is that I still need to wait for the initial request before page would be served. also after I refresh the page.. so there are also no caching :(